# Convert Raster to shapefile with gdal translate

Tags: pyqgis, gdal-translate, virtual-raster

I use this code to get a polygon from a rasters (vrt) extend:

```
# 1
processing.run('gdal:translate',                 
  {'INPUT': r"path/clip2x.vrt", 'OUTPUT': r"path/translate_mask.vrt",  'EXTRA': '-b mask', 'NODATA': 0})
# 2
processing.run('gdal:translate',                  
  {'INPUT': r"path/translate_mask.vrt",'OUTPUT': r"path/translate2.vrt", 'EXTRA': '-b 1', 'NODATA': 0})
# 3
processing.run('gdal:polygonize',                   
  {'INPUT': r"path/translate2.vrt", 'OUTPUT': r"path/polygon_footprint.gpkg", 'BAND': 1})
```

Why is the second step needed? I understand that in the first step, the first band of the input raster gets "masked", meaning all pixel values are projected to a single value?

I am actually pretty sure that I have this code from a stackexchange answer, but I just cannot find it anymore. It had 3 screenshots with the results of each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in the first step, although you specify `'NODATA': 0`, for some reason GDAL ignores that and doesn't set the nodata value in the output vrt.

So the 2nd step sets the nodata value correctly. This maybe a bug you could report to GDAL.

Here's a simple example that replicates the issue (using commandline GDAL in Linux instead of `processing.run`):

```
# Count the number of lines containing the text "NoDataValue"
gdal_translate -of vrt -b mask -a_nodata 0 https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/raw/master/autotest/gdrivers/data/int16.tif /vsistdout|grep -c NoDataValue
```

0

```
# Count the number of lines containing the text "NoDataValue"
gdal_translate -of vrt -b 1 -a_nodata 0 https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/raw/master/autotest/gdrivers/data/int16.tif /vsistdout|grep -c NoDataValue
```

1